# Using DPDK to create a tcp/ip connection

Tags: network-programming, tcp, dpdk

I was wondering if there is a way to use DPDK to make TCP connection in user space without having to copy packet from memory??

I am fairly new to this and I do not know where to start, any advice on how to start would be helpful. I have tried googling for some hints or if anyone has asked and I have not been able to find a lot of resources.

Comment: Do you already have a TCP/IP stack in place, to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

DPDK is a set of libraries and drivers for fast packet processing. It does not have TCP/IP stack out of the box.

So to make a TCP connection you need a TCP/IP stack on top of the DPDK. There are a variety of stacks, for example:

- F-Stack http://www.f-stack.org/
- TLDK https://wiki.fd.io/view/TLDK

and many others...

So just pick whatever you like and start the journey...